# How to do Relative GUI Development in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am used to making android applications and I would like to also make desktop applications. I would prefer to use Python. Is there a module that allows relative layout to better fit all monitors? I have tried pyside, but I could only get absolute. I saw the Kivy module as well, but I didn't want to devote a lot of time to it if it isn't what I need. I am developing on a windows platform for windows, but plan to possibly port it to linux and mac as well. I also would prefer to use Python 3.

Comment: do you how to create a desktop GUI in Python that follows [Responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) approach?

Comment: I do not. Do you have some suggestions on sources I could look at? I am new to desktop applications.

Comment: My previous comment should start with: "do you *want to know* how to.."

Comment: I don't see why not. I honestly don't know which direction to go or if Python is even the best programming language for desktop application development. I am also well versed in Java, but Python is so much nicer.

Comment: The comment is not a suggestion; it is an (unsuccessful) attempt to clarify your question because it is the first time I've encountered "relative GUI" term. Most [GUI frameworks](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) (including Qt (PySide)) should allow relative positioning but I don't know any classic desktop framework that encourages "responsive web design" approach specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). It works on Windows, Linux, and Mac, and is simple enough such that you can pick it up in a weekend. There is plenty of support and documentation as well.

Consider [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) as well--it would satisfy your needs.

Comment: Isn't wxPython just for Python 2?

Comment: There's a version that runs on Python 3 called [ProjectPhoenix](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix)